# forEach() is not supposed to respect ordering, but here it seems to respect, why?

Tags: java, foreach, lambda, java-8

I have been trying to do a little basic GA implementation myself. I used a class `Gene` which wraps a binary bit, a `Chromosome` class that has an `ArrayList` named `genes` of `Gene` objects. In the `Chromosome` class I have an evaluation method `value()` that simply computes the decimal equivalent of the bits in the chromosome. The overridden `toString()` method in `Chromosome` class uses a lambda expression to create a String representation of the bits in the `Gene` objects contained in the ArrayList `genes`. My question is: since `forEach()` method is not supposed to respect the ordering (for the benefit of parallelism), why does it always return the correct string representation of the underlying bits, i.e. in the order in which they were created? Or am I missing something serious here? May it be because of very short chromosome length, that the 'disrespecting' of the ordering is not prominent here?

Here are my classes.

The `Gene` class

```
public class Gene {

    private short value;

    public Gene() {
        value = (short) (Math.random() <= 0.5 ? 0 : 1);
        System.out.print(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```

The `Chromosome` class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Chromosome {

    private ArrayList<Gene> genes;

    public Chromosome(int numOfGene) {
        this.genes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfGene; i++) {
            this.genes.add(i, new Gene());
        }
    }

    public int value() {
        return Integer.parseInt(this.toString(), 2);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder chromosome = new StringBuilder("");

        genes.stream().forEach((g) -> chromosome.append(g));

        return chromosome.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Chromosome c = new Chromosome(10);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

The print statement in `Gene` constructor is to see the order in which the genes were created. No matter how many times I run the program, the `forEach()` always gives the correct representation of the bits, which is confusing for me. Or am I completely ignorant of how this is supposed to work, I know not :-(

Comment: Keep in mind that parallel streams are there to allow implementations to support parallel execution.  But an implementation that doesn't support parallel execution isn't required to go out of its way to process items in a non-sequential order.  So on some implementations, any stream operation could be processed in order, even when it's not **required** to respect the order.  Of course, the other answers have explained why this stream will always be processed sequentially.

Comment: Note that the idiomatic way would be `return genes.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(joining());`.

Comment: @ajb great, you have just added salt to this ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a sequential Stream, the order of the input list is preserved. If you change it to

```
genes.parallelStream().forEach((g) -> chromosome.append(g));
```

You would probably get a different order.

Comment: And then again, you might not.  `forEach` on a parallel stream is not guaranteed to process things in any particular order, but there may be implementations that don't support parallelism, and those would probably just process everything in sequential order.

Comment: perfect! So any `stream` created is actually a serial stream. To make it parallel, `parallelStream` is needed. Thanks. I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

Since genes is an ArrayList, and a List is ordered, you are basically printing the List according to how you added the stuff to it. Basically, the first to be printed is the first that was inputted.

If it was a parallelStream, the order would be random.

Takes a look at this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html#ordering) which explains the forEach in an excellent way.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent answers given! But I would like to add this for future readers, as I found this stated very clearly in the link given by bajada93.

> When you create a stream, it is always a serial stream unless otherwise specified. To create a parallel stream, invoke the operation Collection.parallelStream.

Which means `forEach` will iterate such collection in the order it was constructed.

[Link: JavaSE tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html#executing_streams_in_parallel)